# Hook to insert content into a particular file when visited

Tags: hooks

I want to insert content from one file anytime a file with a particular name is opened, i have this:

```
(defun insert-foo-bar(filename)
  (when (string= (file-name-nondirectory filename) "foo")
    (insert-file-contents "~/bar")))

(add-hook 'find-file-hook 'insert-foo-bar)
```

However after visiting a file with C-x C-f i get a "wrong number of arguments" error. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: When you call function from hook it have no arguments, but your function `insert-foo-bar` needs one - `filename`. Change your question if you want to get an answer with code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this version of your function

```lisp
(defun insert-foo-bar ()
  (when (string= (find-file-nondirectory buffer-file-name) "foo")
    (insert-file-contents "~/bar")))

(add-hook 'find-file-hook 'insert-foo-bar)
```

Or shorter

```lisp
(add-hook 'find-file-hook (lambda ()
  (when (string= (find-file-nondirectory buffer-file-name) "foo")
    (insert-file-contents "~/bar"))))
```

Comment: `buffer-file-name` (without something else added to the equation) will *never* equal `foo` -- the doc-string states (in part):  "*This should be an absolute file name.*"  The original poster has indicated that he/she wishes to use the function `file-name-nondirectory` to ascertain the top level name of the file.

Comment: @lawlist you are right, I have changed that part to this  (when (string= (file-name-nondirectory buffer-file-name) "foo") and it works as expected

Comment: I'll fix it, sorry, mistake.